# Other layout strategy for table of content as navigation

Tags: website-design, navigation

Our website has many nested pages (more than 200) and we are asked to create a navigation **that is not menu bar** since it's so many. So I have designed an `iframe`, fixed on the left side of the screen, with a list fully collapsible and expandable, more like a table of contents. I also put a search field at the top, for easier navigation. Now when I present it to them, they said...

> *"The list at the left looked unnatural, maybe a list navigation wasn't the thing appropriate for this"*.

Are there any other way to make a navigation for lists with many nodes?

Comment: What is the nature of the website? If it is something like products with departments and categories then I don't see why a smart left navigation can't work.

Comment: @Varedis The context of the site something sort of a documentation. Imagine the official API documentation of JQuery.js or how the lessons on wschools are organized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen horizontal navs with a great many options in them and they can be made to work fairly effectively

The example I have here is from "maplin.co.uk" - an electronics store that has many "departments" each with it's own set of 'sub departments':

[image: Maplin.co.uk - complex navigation structures]